# Raycasting in React-three-Fiber in Expo/React-Native Mobile app

Tags: react-native, three.js, expo, raycasting, react-three-fiber

I created a Expo Mobile app with one screen having threejs animation. I used React-three-fiber in it. Each of the three wheels is a group of six planegeometry meshes. Now, i need to use Raycasting to idenify the mesh touched by the Mobile app user. I tried to use the onClick event directly for the groups/meshes but it working on only the top one-third portion of the group/wheel ( don' know why). So, i need to use the raycasting to identify the intersecting objects. But i don't know how to do raycasting in Mobile app in combination with React-three-fiber. So, any sandbox app or sample code will be of great help. [Screenshot of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IlLf.jpg)